# What is a good translation to "end up" somewhere?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

How can I be able to express that something will "end up" in a particular place or situation?

For example:

- "If you keep getting in trouble, you may **end up** in jail."
- "With good marks, you may **end up** studying in Harvard."
- "You'll **end up** in the hospital if you don't keep your seatbelt on."

Is there a way to express this in French, or is it entirely dependent on the situation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Le plus souvent, on utilise simplement *finir* pour « end up ».

- If you keep getting in trouble, you may end up in jail.

  > Tu risques de finir/de te retrouver en prison.
- With good marks, you may end up studying in Harvard.

  > …, tu finiras/réussira peut-être par/à étudier à Harvard
- You'll end up in the hospital if you don't keep your seatbelt on.

  > Tu finiras/termineras à l'hopital si…

Comment: « Réussir par étudier » ça me semble douteux, ça mériterait une petite correction il me semble.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez plus que douteux en effet, merci.

Answer (score 11):

You could use *se retrouver* in a lot of places where you say **end up** in English.

> Si tu n'arrêtes pas tes bêtises, tu vas te retrouver en prison!
>
> Vous allez vous retrouver à l'hôpital si vous ne bouclez pas votre ceinture.

I think this is more often used with a negative/unwanted place/situation to end up in, probably a bit more so than how you use **to end up** in English.
In speech, you can even go for a bit of redundancy to mark your point:

> Si tu continues à avoir de si bonnes notes, tu vas finir par te retrouver à Harvard!

(Even if the outcome is, in fact, desirable, which I presume is the case above.)

The above is slightly informal. In more formal contexts, simply using the verb *finir*, suitably conjugated, will work just fine as [jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2622/241) mentions.

Answer (score 2):

[Aboutir](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/french-english/aboutir) is actually the verb you are looking for in this case.

Ex:  Si tu ne respectes pas les lois, tu va aboutir en prison.

Comment: The verb is a good suggestion, however the example sounds a bit odd. Maybe it's because *aboutir* is in a quite high langage level (or register) and the example used would suggest a more common register, if not slang. Good answer nonetheless.